# What is discovery url of Okta

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, okta

I am implementing authentication using openid connect. I have successfully implemented the openid - connect in my website. I am using well known url (https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration) to get the endpoint detail so method should be generic for all the sources (Google, Microsoft etc).

I want to authenticate the user using okta. I did not find discover url of okta so that I can fetch the endpoint details of okta.

Can any one provide me the well known url of okta?

Answer (score 7):

If you've [created a developer account](https://developer.okta.com/signup/), you can use your instance's URL to find it. For example, my instance's URL is dev-158606.oktapreview.com and my well-known OIDC info is at https://dev-158606.oktapreview.com/.well-known/openid-configuration.